# Regular Expression for grok matching pattern

Tags: regex

I need the same **Regex** for below two lines.

```
  PieceID = NEW00000009

  piece_id="NEW00000009"
```

**find my pattern:**

```
[pP]iece[_]*[iI][dD][" "]*=[" "]*["]*(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]["]*{11})"
```

Comment: `[pP]iece_?[iI][dD] ?= ?"?(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{11}"?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not far from the good pattern, but you need several clarifications:

- To make something optional use `?` (that means `{0,1}`) instead of `*` (that means `{0,}`).
- you don't need to put quotes around a space, the space character has nothing special. Even a character were special, you never need to protect it with quotes.

Your pattern can be written like this:

```
[pP]iece_?[iI][dD] *= *"?(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{11})"?
```

You can be a little more rigorous, avoiding to match something like `piece_id=NEW00000009"`:

```
[pP]iece_?[iI][dD] *= *("?)(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{11})\\1
```

<sup>The optional quote is captured in group 1 and `\\1` is a back-reference for the group 1</sup>

To finish you can make it more flexible if you replace spaces with `\\s*` (`\\s` is a character class for any white-spaces) or `[^\\S\\r\\n]*` that allows only horizontal white-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to worry about case-sensitivity with this one, but I think it will do what you're trying to do.

```
var s1 = "PieceID = NEW00000009";
var s2 = @"piece_id=""NEW00000009""";

var re = new Regex(@"^(PieceID|piece_id)\s*=\s*\""?(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{11})\""?$");

Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch(s1));
Console.WriteLine(re.IsMatch(s2));
```

Output:

```
True
True
```